# URL regenerate in magento 2

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite, seo

I am developing my website in Magento 2, I need URL regenerate for products after I changed the category URL.

URL's are not changing for existing products.

Ex:

Category URL's:
New URL:
 http://test.com/jewellery-collections/gold-jewellery/gold-rings
Old URL:
 http://test.com/collections/gold/rings

Product URL's:
 http://test.com/collections/gold/rings/midas-bloom

but the URL should be 
 http://test.com/jewellery-collections/gold-jewellery/gold-ringsmidas-bloom

So, Product URL's should be regenerate as per new category URL

Comment: Hey first  truncate you core_url_rewrite, and then  re-index your database, Let me know if any issue

Comment: @sanjay url_rewrite is not working in magento 2 after reindex also  i used php bin/magento indexer:reindex this command to re-index

Comment: go in you php my admin and search  SELECT * FROM `url_rewrite`  and after this  run my sql query TRUNCATE url_rewrite, then  use comond on your cli, indexer:reindex . I am very sure your problem will be sort out